# Run a Java EE project divided by 4

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, glassfish

I'm using Netbeans to run a Java ee web project. I chose to try with the GlassFish server. The project is divided in 4 projects :

[image]

So I want to run the four projects at the same time, because it's only one project. I'm also using Maven and I have created the dependencies for every project (4 BUILD SUCCESSFUL).

I tried to run the second project because it's the one which has the index.jsp. But I have an error 500 :

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> type Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation
>   for JSP
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: source value 1.5 is obsolete and
>   will be removed in a future release
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: target value 1.5 is obsolete and
>   will be removed in a future release
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: To suppress warnings about obsolete
>   options, use -Xlint:-options.
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: package javax.servlet does not exist
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: package javax.servlet.http does not
>   exist
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: package javax.servlet.jsp does not
>   exist
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: package org.apache.jasper.runtime
>   does not exist
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: package org.apache.jasper.runtime
>   does not exist
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
>   JspFactory   location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: package org.glassfish.jsp.api does
>   not exist
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
>   HttpServletRequest   location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
>   HttpServletResponse   location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
>   ServletException   location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find symbol   symbol:
>   variable JspFactory   location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
>   PageContext   location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
>   HttpSession   location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
>   ServletContext   location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
>   ServletConfig   location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
>   JspWriter   location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
>   JspWriter   location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
>   PageContext   location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: package org.glassfish.jsp.api does
>   not exist
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error: package org.apache.jasper.runtime
>   does not exist
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 41 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error: package org.apache.jasper.runtime
>   does not exist
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 42 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error: package org.apache.jasper.runtime
>   does not exist
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 46 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error: package org.apache.jasper.runtime
>   does not exist
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 114 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error: package org.apache.jasper.runtime
>   does not exist
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
>   SkipPageException   location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
>   ServletException   location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

I think that this exception happened because it's running only one project.
Can someone help me to resolve this problem please ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try and deploy the top level maven project (the parent).

normally in JAVA EE you will see something like this.

pom root all the project modules are defined here.

After that there is your EAR file. The ear file will contain depencies to your EJB and your JSP project and other modules if you have any.

Then when you try to deploy you application to glassfish you need to deploy your EAR module. Glassfish will then deploy everything for you out of the box.

ref: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/04/java-ee7-and-maven-project-for-newbies-part-1-a-simple-maven-project-structure-the-parent-pom.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try ! :)

Comment: I only have a pom parent, but no parent project, so I can't deploy just a pom, isn't it ? And I don't know if it's because of this, but when I try to run the EAR project, I can't select the GlassFish server.